# Change second dropdown based on first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the second dropdown based on the selection of the first one, but it is not working right now. I'm using bootstrap select's selectpicker and form-group class, although I'm not sure if it caused the problem.

The second dropdown is disabled before the first one is selected, and only show items that match the data group selection.

HTML:

```
<select id="seasons" class="selectpicker form-group" title="Choose season" onchange="filterSeason();">
    <option value='2013-14'>2013-14</option>
    <option value='2014-15'>2014-15</option>
    <option value='2015-16'>2015-16</option>
    <option value='2016-17'>2016-17</option>
</select>
<select id="clubs" class="selectpicker form-group" title="Choose club" disabled>
    <optgroup data-group='2013-14' label="England">
        <option data-group='2013-14' value='ENG1'>Team 1</option>
        <option data-group='2013-14' value='ENG2'>Team 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-group='2014-15' label="Spain">
        <option data-group='2014-15' value='SPA1'>Team 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-group='2015-15' label="Germany">
        <option data-group='2015-16' value='GER1'>Team 4</option>
        <option data-group='2015-16' value='GER2'>Team 5</option>
        <option data-group='2015-16' value='GER3'>Team 6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
function filterSeason() {
      var seasons = $("#seasons").find('option:selected').text(); 
      $("#option-container").children().appendTo("#clubs");
      var selectSeason = $("#clubs").children("[data-group!='"+seasons+"']"); 
      selectSeason.appendTo("#option-container");
      $("#clubs").removeAttr("disabled");
};
```

Comment: So you want only the items with the data-group to be selebtable? pls include the `#option-container` values also to your question

Comment: I think : <optgroup data-group='2015-15' label="Germany"> should be <optgroup data-group='2015-16' label="Germany">

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you needed if I understood correctly.

use `$("#clubs").children().removeAttr('disabled');` to enable all children and then disable which are not relevant with this `$(selectSeason).attr('disabled','disabled');`

Please check this fiddle

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/La6j948j/1/)

Comment: Thanks! @Muhammed Shevil KP. Works without the class, but still doesn't work with the class. Guess there might be some conflicts.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by `Works without the class, but still doesn't work with the class`

Comment: I mean I have to delete "class="selectpicker form-group"" to make it work

Comment: but it works without make any change to that class. please check the fiddle updated

Comment: This question helps solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317296/how-to-enable-disable-bootstrap-selectpicker-by-ickeck-checkbox

Comment: I solved the problem with the question above. Thanks for you help!